# Debian 11 (bullseye): user cron jobs not running

Tags: bash, debian, cron

I have a server that I am hosting at home using a residential ISP that issues public IP addresses via DHCP--that is to say, I don't always get the same IP back when my DCHP lease renews. I created a bash script to check whether my public IP has changed, and to e-mail me the new IP address if it has changed. The "current" IP is stored in a text file in my home directory that is globally readable and writeable. I'd like to run this hourly, but I can't seem to get cron to run *any* jobs for me. The script runs without any issues.

I've reviewed previous questions and I don't think there are issues with file permissions or output handling problems. The file/job just never shows up in /var/log/syslog.

Thoughts?

##### Versioning

System Details (`uname -a`): `Linux jasonbourne 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

cron details (`apt info cron`): `Version: 3.0pl1-137`

bash details (`apt info bash`): `Version: 5.1-2+deb11u1`

##### The Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#known (current) IP
current_ip=`cat /home/jasonbourne/.current_ip`

#check for actual IP
check_ip=`dig -4 +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

if [ $check_ip != $current_ip ]
then
    message="`hostname`'s IP address changed from $current_ip to $check_ip on `date +%D` at `date +%T`"
    email="jasonbourne@jasonbourne.com"
    subject="`hostname` IP address change!"
    echo $message | mail -r $email -s "$subject" $email
    echo $check_ip > /home/jasonbourne/.current_ip
fi
```

The script and my current IP have appropriate permissions:

```
jasonbourne@debian:~$ ls -la /usr/bin/public-ip-monitor.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 873 Dec 28 20:14 /usr/bin/public-ip-monitor.sh
```

```
jasonbourne@debian:~$ ls -la /home/jasonbourne/.current_ip
-rw-rw-rw- 1 jasonbourne jasonbourne 15 Dec 28 21:28 /home/jasonbourne/.current_ip
```

##### The crontab and cron.time Attempts:

The cron service is running just fine:

```
jasonbourne@debian:~$ sudo systemctl status cron
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-28 00:32:37 EST; 21h ago
       Docs: man:cron(8)
   Main PID: 14242 (cron)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4583)
     Memory: 1.0M
        CPU: 3.949s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             └─14242 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

I've set my user crontab with `crontab -e` and I've tried `0 * * * * /usr/bin/public-ip-monitor.sh` and `@hourly /usr/bin/public-ip-monitor.sh`. I've also placed the script in `/etc/cron.hourly`.

Comment: what does /var/log/syslog say? are there any cron logs?

Comment: @Alex - plenty of cron activity. There's some `sendmail` activity every 20 minutes, and the hourly jobs look like they should be getting run, e.g.: `Dec 28 20:17:01 debian CRON[38218]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`. While testing `/etc/cron.hourly` (typo in OP, will fix), I left the script in the directory overnight but it never showed up in the logs.

Comment: If the system has a working Mail Transfer Agent (e.g. exim/postfix/sendmail), most `cron` implementations would send cron job errors as local email, which would end up in `/var/mail/root` for jobs in `/etc/cron.hourly` or in `/var/mail/<username>` for jobs in user crontabs. Anything in there?

Comment: @telcoM, I have a working MTA (sendmail). There are no emails to any user or root.

Comment: I'd expect some messages from `cron` if it failed to execute the script. I'm also curious if you've enabled SE Linux; that *could* prevent execution if things aren't set up properly.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I'm concerned that the lack of `cron` messages/logs means the script/job simply isn't running, period--the `crontab`  job or my script in `cron.hourly` don't seem to be getting executed.

Comment: I see from https://askubuntu.com/a/607974/619216 that Debian wants a specific filename format for scripts under /etc/cron.daily/; can you show the filename you used for that directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, it was `/etc/cron.hourly/public-ip-monitor.sh`, global executable, with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, I re-read the question you posted and realized that `.` is not in the character space. Aha! I will test and report back.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, you found it - unsupported namespace character (`.`). My jobs are still not showing up in `/var/log/syslog` but `/etc/cron.hourly/public-ip-monitor` (without `.sh`) sent me an email! If you want to turn that into an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that `/etc/cron.hourly/public-ip-monitor.sh` didn't work is because the hourly cron entries are initiated via `run-parts` in the /etc/crontab file:

```bash
01 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

[run-parts](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debianutils/run-parts.8.en.html) has certain rules about what it runs:

> run-parts runs all the executable files named within constraints described below, found in directory directory.

> If neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits, ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

As a result, a file that's named with a `.sh` extension will not be run.

Hat tip to [kenorb](https://askubuntu.com/users/78223/kenorb)'s [AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/607974/619216) for pointing me in this direction.